# How to get device location every 5 minutes using background service in Android?

Tags: android, service, geolocation, location, android-intentservice

I want to fetch user location every 5 minutes and display as `Toast`. Which is the best way to do this? `Service` or `IntentService`? I want to start and stop the service on button click. How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use a alarm service to trigger location service which will inturn save location in database table

```
public static void setAlarmTimely(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.ALARM_INTENT, IntentConstants.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_TRACK);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(context, IntentConstants.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_TRACK, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    LOGD(TAG, time + " ");
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + locationCaptureTime * 60 * 1000,
            5 * 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
}
```

on button click cancel the alarm

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    LOGD(TAG, "cancelling location update");
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.ALARM_INTENT, IntentConstants.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_TRACK);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(context, IntentConstants.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_TRACK, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with LocationManager, you need to set time interval.

example

```
LocationManager = new LocationManager();
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

Parameters

provider    String: the name of the provider with which to register

minTime long: minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds

minDistance float: minimum distance between location updates, in meters

listener    LocationListener: a LocationListener whose

onLocationChanged(Location) method will be called for each location update

you can read more on this page
[LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener))

Answer (score 0):

Use sticky Service to do this

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Service Started");
        try {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Then call this from oncreate of service

```
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Awake - "+i);
              //  Log.i(LOG_TAG,"TEST ALARM TIME");
            //  do your task -- here get location 
            //change the time interval as per your need.

           handler.postDelayed(this, 300000);
            }
        },1000);
    }
```